# Copy top fifteen elements from one array to another one

Tags: scala

I'm trying to make a simple one top fifteen with this code:

```
    var top = Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
    val numbers = Array(4,5,8,1,33,23,45,6,11,10,87,46,43,66,55,98,78,71,19,20)


    def getTop() : Unit = {
        for ( i <- 0 to (numbers.length - 1)) {
            set(0, numbers(i), top)
        }

        top.map(x => println(x))
    }

    def set(index: Int, number: Int, top: Array[Int]) : Unit = {
        if (index <= top.length-1) {
            if(top(index) < number) {
                top(index) = number
            }
            else {
                set(index+1, number, top)
            }
        }
    }
```

The function should copy the top fifteen elements that are in the array `numbers` to array `top`, but currently I get only:

```
98,78,71,20,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why don't you write just `val top = numbers.sorted.take(15)`?

Comment: @om-nom-nom: actually `numbers.sorted.reverse.take(15)`, but otherwise you are right.

Comment: I wanted to avoid using the maximum use of library functions to understand the use of recursive functions and cycles.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz or numbers.sorted(Ordering[Int].reverse).take(15)

Comment: That's scalaized java. If you're after learning, try returning values from your functions based on the parameters instead of mutating the structures passed. Try your sort  and top functions using recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you overriding previously set numbers:

```
top = Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)  //initially  
top = Array(4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)  // let's call set for '4'  
top = Array(5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)  // now for 5 ...   
top = Array(8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)  
top = Array(8,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)  
....
```

You can fix it with adjacent placing number you're replacing to the right place:

```
val top = Array.fill(15)(0)
val numbers = Array(4,5,8,1,33,23,45,6,11,10,87,46,43,66,55,98,78,71,19,20)


def printTop() : Unit = {
    for (n <- numbers) {
        set(0, n, top)
    }

    top.foreach(x => println(x))
}

def set(index: Int, number: Int, top: Array[Int]) : Unit = {
    if (index < top.length) {
        val current = top(index)
        if(current < number) {
            top(index) = number
            set(index+1, current, top) // send replaced number down the street
        }
        else {
            set(index+1, number, top)
        }
    }
}
```